How to resolve "ERR_REQUIRE_ESM" for ESM dependencies when bundling a Node.js API with Rollup to CommonJS?
I'm working on bundling a Node.js API written with ES module (import/export) syntax and targeting CommonJS (CJS) as the output format using Rollup. However, after bundling the app and trying to start it, I run into issues with ESM-only third-party node modules, which are the majority of the dependencies.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /api/node_modules/.pnpm/node-fetch@3.3.2/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /api/dist/route-DpPSLTSv.js not supported.
Instead, change the require of index.js in /api/dist/route-DpPSLTSv.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

My goal is to configure Rollup to handle this ESM-to-CJS issue without needing to manually switch all the require() statements to dynamic import().
Here’s my current Rollup configuration:
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import nodeExternals from 'rollup-plugin-node-externals'
import sentryRollupPlugin from 'rollup-plugin-sentry'

const { SENTRY_ORG, SENTRY_PROJECT, SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN } = process.env

/**
 * @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions}
 */
const config = {
  input: ['src/index.ts', 'instrument.js'],
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: true
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.json', '.mjs', '.cjs']
    }),
    commonjs(),
    nodeExternals(),
    typescript(),
    json(),
    sentryRollupPlugin({
      org: SENTRY_ORG,
      project: SENTRY_PROJECT,
      authToken: SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
      include: ['dist'],
      ignore: ['node_modules']
    })
  ],
  onwarn(warning, handler) {
    if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') {
      return
    }

    handler(warning)
  }
}

export default config

